# Can't update Cyanogenmod on AT&T Galaxy S III

Tags: cyanogenmod, updates, samsung-galaxy-s

I updated to Cyanogenmod 10.1 RC 2 and can't update beyond it. When I try to update to RC5, I get:

```
assert failed: getprop("ro.bootloader") not matching
"I747UCDLK3" or "I747MVLDLK4" or "I747MUMBLK3" or "I747MUMBLL1"
```

Which naturally causes the update to be cancelled

Does anyone have a link that shows how to resolve this, or other suggestions to resolve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message is basically telling you that you don't have the correct bootloader version on your device; specifically, you most likely have an older ICS bootloader rather than the Jelly Bean one. You can read a bit about this on [CyanogenMod's Google+ page](https://plus.google.com/+CyanogenMod/posts/UzrLe6wtk5d), and the CM Wiki page for the S3 [succinctly notes](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_d2att#Important_Notes):

> Going forward, CM10.1 is no longer compatible with ICS bootloaders on this device. Please update or else you will get assert failures in recovery.

You'll need to upgrade to a newer bootloader. This carries some amount of risk since it's one of the few instances where you could potentially brick a device, but the risk is still generally pretty small.

I found links to the newer AT&T bootloader [on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=41503727&postcount=13716) that will work with CM 10.1. You can flash them using [Odin](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2189539) or [Heimdall](http://www.glassechidna.com.au/products/heimdall/) by following [these instructions](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=41503727&postcount=13716):

> 1. Go here http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=41503727&postcount=13716
> 2. Put phone into download mode and then open Odin.
> 3. Choose the PDA slot and then select the correct file for your device (AT&T is LK3)
> 4. Hit start and wait until its finished.
> 5. Done

Comment: Thanks for answering so clearly, when obviously it's something I *should* have been able to find on my own. Don't know why I couldn't find it. I was able to update to RC5 successfully.

Comment: Odin3 v3.07 works with SGH-I747, even though it is not listed on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up [following the instructions here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2321310) and was then able to update to 10.1.3RC2. No need to install Odin or Heimdall on your computer :)